# Is there an open source tool to measure cpu performance?

Tags: linux, performance, opensource-projects

I have used many times [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) for measuring web performance, [`hdparm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm) for measuring hard disk performance and [`netperf`](http://www.netperf.org) for measuring network performance.

But I didn't find any tools to measure cpu performance.

Do you know a tool allowing to measure cpu performance? I am more specifically looking to measure Gflops.

Comment: see "http://serverfault.com/questions/88357/estimate-flops-in-linux" for measuring gflops and you can use mpstat or sar command for cpu performance

Comment: sar and mpstat indicates cpu activity, not cpu performance. Serverfault question indicates to use LINPACK, which is not open source.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634513/cpu-benchmarking-utility-for-linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Wikipedia page on benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)#Open_source_benchmarks), it gives quite a few benchmark tools including the CPU ones that will work on Linux. [LinPack](http://www.netlib.org/linpack/) is free but a pain to compile. But you can certainly look at [NBench](http://www.tux.org/~mayer/linux/bmark.html) and some others in the list.

Comment: NBench is good, but 15 year old code. We need something new. The link is stale BTW.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ date; i=0; while (( i < 1000000 )); do (( i ++ )); done; date
Tue Jul 15 11:26:37 EDT 2014
Tue Jul 15 11:26:43 EDT 2014
$
```

Comment: Would that be 43 - 37 = 6 GigaFlops? I fail to see how an integer increment in a shell, relates to floating point performance.

Comment: The general goal was "measure cpu performance". Later mentions Gflops but I think that's actually a misguided tangent. If Gflops was the true goal then asking about CPU performance was a mistake.

Comment: Quicker way to get to the number you're really after, i.e. *seconds that have passed*:

`DATE=$(date +%s); i=0; while (( i < 1000000 )); do (( i ++ )); done; echo $(( $(date +%s)-DATE ))`

Comment: Good point, I should have updated this earlier. Here's my current approach: time ( i=0; while (( i < 1000000 )); do (( i ++ )); done )

Comment: This is not 6 gigaflops, this is ~0.17 megabashincrements.   And, my macbook owns all: `( i=0 ; while (( i < 1000000 )); do; (( i ++ )); done; )  1.33s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.337 total`

Comment: This will tell you far more about the version of bash or type of shell being used than the performance of your CPU.

Answer (score 3):

[stress-ng](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/) is a simple tool that can stress and benchmark the cpus.

For example, tested 1 cpu

`stress-ng -c 1 --cpu-ops 5000`

> stress-ng: info:  [20288] defaulting to a 86400 second run per stressor
>
> stress-ng: info:  [20288] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu
>
> stress-ng: info:  [20288] successful run completed in 13.93s

Comment: I think advising a stress testing program to benchmark is misleading: there is a big difference between benchmarking and stressing a CPU.